# A lot of spacing under my <h1> tags?

Tags: html

Hello I am making a dummy promotion page and I am not sure why I have so much
spacing under my h1 tags.

Also for my footer, my li's dont seem to inherit the hover effect?
My li:hover works locally but not when I transfer it over on ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around on your site I found some problems (Chrome inspect is a powerful tool)

In your css/style.css you're setting the hover style on the < li> element, but it's the < a> element you should change the styling of. Change nav li:hover and h1 to this:

```
nav a:hover {
    background: #222; // Looks better
    color: #1CDFED;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```